# A JavaScript promise is not working on a HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

The problem with the code is that I inputted everything right and nothing is showing up. Code for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>order</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo"></div>

  <script>
    let tag = document.getElementById("demo");

    function display(value) {
      tag.innerHTML = value;
    }

    let toldThePeople = "BBQ Cauliflower";

    // Restaurant order 
    let restaurantOrder = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let order = "BBQ Corn";

      if (toldThePeople === order) {
        resolve("Mmm, You guys did an awesome job!");
      } else {
        reject("I WANT THE MANAGER!!!");
      }
    });

    restaurantOrder.then(function (value) {
      display(value);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As shown there is a promise which should work but isnt.

---

I tried to play the code and it would not show up. Is there any wrong reference? Is the html code wrong?

Comment: Since you are rejecting the promise, you should handle the case with a `.catch()` after the `.then()`. Is there a reason why you are using a Promise instead of returning form a regular function? ^^

Comment: "BBQ Cauliflower" doesn't match "BBQ Corn", so the promise rejects.

Comment: Change your `reject` to `resolve` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Make sure your linking correctly to your css file.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `reject` of the promise is being called which doesn't enter `then` but instead causes the `catch` to be called:

```
restaurantOrder.then((value) => {
  display(value); // when resolve is called
}).catch((value) => {
  display(value); // when reject is called
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as I see promise is working fine. I think you are expecting the reject(promise) value in .then function. When the promise get reject then catch block code execute. You need to add catch block for reject case of promise as mentioned below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>order</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo"></div>

  <script>
    let tag = document.getElementById("demo");

    function display(value) {
      tag.innerHTML = value;
    }

    let toldThePeople = "BBQ Cauliflower";

    // Restaurant order 
    let restaurantOrder = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      let order = "BBQ Corn";

      if (toldThePeople === order) {
        resolve("Mmm, You guys did an awesome job!");
      } else {
        reject("I WANT THE MANAGER!!!");
      }
    });

    restaurantOrder.then(function (value) {
      display(value);
    }).catch((value)=>{
        display(value);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```